# How can I access DialogFlow parameters using DialogFlowApp or ActionsSDKApp client library?

Tags: actions-on-google

I'm using DialogFlow to create a Google Assistant Application. For fullfilment I'm using a custom app with NodeJS client library.

I noted that when DialogFlow's request get my application I can see all **request**, also the parameters object

```
const astronomyAssistant = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const app = new DialogflowApp({ request, response });
  console.log(`Request headers: ${JSON.stringify(request.headers)}`);
  console.log(`Request body: ${JSON.stringify(request.body)}`);
  app.handleRequest(actionMap);
});
```

There some way to access the **request** object inside of a handle action? How can I access request object using app?

## Workaround:

You can put all handle function that depends of *request* object inside of functions.https.onRequest callback.

For instance:

```
const astronomyAssistant = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const app = new DialogflowApp({ request, response });
  console.log(`Request headers: ${JSON.stringify(request.headers)}`);
  console.log(`Request body: ${JSON.stringify(request.body)}`);

  const foo = app => {
     console.log(request);
  }

  actionMap.set('input.foo', foo);

  app.handleRequest(actionMap);
});
```

But, for sure this is not a good practice.

Comment: Why do you feel that isn't a good practice?

Comment: Hi @Prisoner, in my opinion put all "handle" methods inside of onRequest function only to be able to get request object isn't a good practice.

Of course, I can create another abstraction level to store the request object, but in my opinion put this method as public on DialogflowApp is the best way to make the code modular.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `app.getArgument("my-parameter")` to quickly access any parameter you've defined within your actions.

Comment: Hi @Nick, I already tried to use getArgument method but without success.

I created a parameter with a Date entity (@sys.date-time) and I can't get this value using getArgument.

This link show a sample of my problem [https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Pk6-3pdHQhjpnHZTfKTdRzc7nRIDdF53](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Pk6-3pdHQhjpnHZTfKTdRzc7nRIDdF53)

Comment: app.getArgument('date-time') is undefined?

Comment: yes the result is undefined. Only by request object I can get this parameter.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the Action & parameters section?

Comment: Yes, [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1tmHr_zy6HUBJYvgf-k7aGA-A12SBITlr) is the screenshot.